# How should I write the width of the body of my document as a condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, sidenav

I'm working on a side navigator menu for a website and obviously I want to make it responsive and it has two different aspects on a large screen as a desktop and on a tighter screen as on a mobile phone. The problem is that I don't know how to write correctly the width of the body of my HTML document as a condition in JavaScript.
That's what I tried but it simply doesn't work, so I thought it could be a syntax error by me.

```
function openMenu() {
   if (document.body.width >= 415) {
      // code to run
   } else if (document.body.width <= 414) {
      // code to run
   }
}
```

Comment: `document.body` doesn't have property `width`

Comment: Try using ```document.body.offsetWidth``` instead of ```document.body.width```

Comment: Remember that [offesetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) returns size without margin.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Ah ok in this case it's gonna be perfect but I'll remember that, thank you